# I want to Extract 7 from this string GRN/GSI/2017/7 using Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I want to Extract 7 from this string GRN/GSI/2017/7 using Regex

I try it but it extract 2017

```
`string s1 = dt2.Rows[0]["Doc_No"].ToString();
                string i1;
                string[] numbers = Regex.Split(s1, @"\D+");
                foreach (string value in numbers)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        i1 = value;
                        txtGRNNo.Text = i1;

                    }
                }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please explain what your "rule" is for extracting that digit? The code you posted will loop through all numbers after splitting the string. "\d+" is 1 or more digits. So in your case both **2017** and **7** will be matched.

Do you always only want the last number?

If so, then this could work for you:

```
string s1 = dt2.Rows[0]["Doc_No"].ToString();
txtGRNNo.Text = Regex.Split(s1, @"/").Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following RegEx patterns:

With a fixed number of characters between / :
`[A-Z]{0,3}\/[A-Z]{0,3}\/[0-9]{0,4}\/([0-9]*)\b`

With a dynamic number of characters between / :
`[A-Z]*\/[A-Z]*\/[0-9]*\/([0-9]*)\b`

On how to use regex, have a look at e.g. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex_methods(v=vs.90).aspx) and the [Match()-methode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx)